# set controller function as link

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have created simple mvc in php.

My controller is :

```
class front
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }
    function add_to_cart()
    {
        echo "123";exit;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to pass id into this controller.

My view page is:

```
<a href="http://localhost/bhajipala_latest/controllers/front.php/add_to_cart/<?php echo $pr_value['itemID']; ?>" class="site-button-dark"><span>ADD TO CART</span></a>
```

So, what link I have to write in **href** to get itemID in add_to_cart function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question but this is simple example of using such functionality

**Test.php**

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="../another_test.php/add_to_cart/?id=1231"/>Click Here</a>';
?>
```

**another_test.php**

```
<?php

class A{

    function __construct(){

    }
    function add_to_cart(){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        return $id;
    }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->add_to_cart();//1231
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{BASE URL : http://localhost/projectname}/{indx.php(ifrequired)}/{CONTROLLER NAME : front}/{METHOD NAME : add_to_cart} / {VALUE : itemID}
```

In short {http://localhost/projectname}/{indx.php}/{front}/{add_to_cart}/{itemID}

```
   function add_to_cart($itemID)
    {
        echo $itemID;exit;
    }
```

Comment: This is just a class not a MVC's controller, You have to write controller. Then your class should extend it. then only you can access it by URL.